# Deployment custom App in Microsoft Teams

Tags: azure, deployment, chatbot, microsoft-teams

I am developing a chatbot azure service, which I want to integrate within Microsoft Teams. So far everything is working but the "re-install" of the package in the Microsoft Teams.

I created a publish "folder-profile". Then I zip the result with the manifest.json and the icon files inside. I go to the Manage Team section and in the Apps tab I select upload a custom app. Then I choose the .zip file and the service seems to be there(Actually it is there)

It works, but when I create a new version and I repeat the described steps, it seems like Microsoft Teams is still using my old code.

I test the chatbot in the Chat by using @"APP-ID" and I see how my changes work, but installed as an App for the "Team" keeps the old version.

I tried to uninstall it, check if the bot is gone(it is gone) and then upload again, but some kind of cache is there and the bot behaves like in the previous version.

Any idea how is the correct way to deploy new versions of my app in Microsoft Teams?

Comment: What's different between the two versions? That is, something is supposed to change but didn't - what is it?

Comment: @BillBliss-MSFT I changed only one line of code where I added a Delay to the chat response, so it looks more realistic.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to upgrade the version number in the `manifest.json` file (you can do it in the `manifest.source.json` before to generate your zip).